# Routing with Angular 4 and SailsJS

Tags: angular, sails.js

I am start a new project with Angular 4 and SailsJS. I have 2 page: `home` and `login`. I use sails for api and use angular route for navigate. 
When I access `/`, it redirect me to `/login` correctly, but if I refresh the page the router doesn't recognize the path and return sails 404 page.

If I had:

```
{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy}
```

in my `app.module.ts` the angular route works but add the `#` (`localhost:8100/# e localhost:8100/#/login`)

can someone help me? :D

this is my sails route:

```
'POST /api/authentication' : 'AuthenticationController.authenticate', 
'/': {
  view: 'homepage',
  skipAssets: true
},
'/*': {
  view: 'homepage',
  skipAssets: true
}
```

EDIT

I resolve this issue mapping in sails routes front-end page, like this:

```
'/': {
   view: 'homepage',
   skipAssets: true
},

'/login': {
   view: 'homepage',
   skipAssets: true
}
```

if someone has a better solution is welcome :)